# Comparing two lists and performing an operation in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `I` and `i`. I want to find for each element of `i`, how many values are less than in `I` and add the total number of such values to the specific `i` element. For example, element `15` in `i` has two values less than itself in `I` i.e. `[8,11]`. So `2` should be added to `15` and the combination stored in `Values`. I present the expected output.

```
I = [8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]

i=[15, 17, 27, 28, 31, 41]
```

The expected output is

```
New i=[17,19,30,31,34,46]
Values=[[8,11],[8,11],[8,11,19],[8,11,19],[8,11,19],[8,11,19,37,40]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your list `I` is sorted, you can use [`bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to get insertion point in your list `I` for each element in `i` and then slice the list. It uses binary search.

With that you can do:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
Values = [I[:bisect_left(I, e)] for e in i]
New_i =  [e + len(Values[j]) for j, e in enumerate(i)]
```

print(Values):

```
[[8, 11], [8, 11], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19, 37, 40]]
```

print(New_i):

```
[17, 19, 30, 31, 34, 46]
```

BTW I highly recommend not to use `I` and `i` for your variable names.

Comment: How do I obtain ```New i``` as shown in the expected output?

Comment: `New_i = [el + len(Values[idx]) for idx, el in enumerate(i)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use two list comprehensions

```py
>>> # for each element in i, add the elements in I to a list if they are smaller
>>> values = [[e for e in I if e < n] for n in i]
>>> # add the element of i to the number of elements in I that are smaller
>>> new_i = [sum(x) for x in zip(i, map(len, values))]
```

```
>>> values
[[8, 11], [8, 11], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19, 37, 40]]
>>> new_i
[17, 19, 30, 31, 34, 46]
```

Answer (score 0):

the other solutions are 100% correct, here's another solution but oldschool and more readable:

```
l1 = [15, 17, 27, 28, 31, 41]
l2 = [8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]
comp = []
for i in l1:
    c = []
    for j in l2:
        if i > j:
            i += 1
            c.append(j)
    comp.append(c)
print(l1)
print(comp)
```

**input >>**

l1 = [15, 17, 27, 28, 31, 41]

l2 = [8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]

**output >>**

[15, 17, 27, 28, 31, 41]

[[8, 11], [8, 11], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use `numpy` which allows quick operations on lists by putting them in matrix form and is more optimized than operations in lists. An example of code could be:

```py
import numpy as np

list_1 = [8, 11, 19, 37, 40, 42]
list_2 = [15, 17, 27, 28, 31, 41]

arr_1, arr_2 = np.array(list_1), np.array(list_2)
# Broadcast to 2D array where elem (i, j) is whether list_2[i] < list_1[j] or not
arr_sup = (arr_2[:, None] - arr_1[None, :]) > 0
# Add sum of rows to list_2 to create the new list
new_list = (np.sum(arr_sup, axis=1) + list_2).tolist()
# Get indexes (i, j) where arr_sup[i, j] is True
idx_sup = np.where(arr_sup)
values = []
for i, j in zip(idx_sup[0], idx_sup[1]):  # browse i and j together
    if len(values) < i + 1:
        # Add a new list for each new i
        values.append([])
    # Add value j of list 1 to i-th list in values
    values[i].append(list_1[j])

print(new_list) # [17, 19, 30, 31, 34, 46]
print(values) # [[8, 11], [8, 11], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19], [8, 11, 19, 37, 40]]
```

It works even if the lists are not sorted.